# How to check if matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: diagonalization, symmetry

Is there any exact ways to check if a matrix is diagonalizable? 
For instance, I have an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and I need to show that $AA^T$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

$AA^T$ is a symmetric matrix so it is diagonalizable.

Comment: ... if $A$ is real.  Not true for complex matrices.

Comment: For example, try $$A = \pmatrix{3/2 & -i/2\cr i & 1\cr},\ AA^T = \pmatrix{2 & i\cr i & 0\cr}$$
which is symmetric but not diagonalizable (eigenvalue $1$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ but geometric multiplicity $1$).

Answer (score 1):

$AA^T$ is symmetrical, hence it is diagonalizable.

For a general square matrix, compute the algebraic multiplicity and the geometric multiplicity for each eigenvalue. They have to be equal for it to be diagonalizable.

Edit: thanks to Robert Israel's comment, I am assuming $A$ is real.

Comment: but if I have an arbitrary matrix and I do not know the elements of a matrix, what should I do then?

Comment: @HelloDarkness What do you know about your matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A$ is a real matrix, note that

$(AA^T)^T = (A^T)^T A^T = AA^T; \tag{1}$

thus $AA^T$ is symmetric.  But symmetric matrices are *always* diagonalizable . . .